# Обработка запроса

Tags: скрипт, ajax, php, запрос

Здравствуйте, мне надо сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку запрос обрабатывался и не переходил на другую страницу. То есть как в ВК, например, при нажатии на кнопку.

html-скрипт:

```
   <span style="display: none;" id="idGroups"><?php echo $hfs["idGroups"]; ?></span>
    <button name="delgroup" id="delgroup">Удалить</button>
```

php-скрипт:

```
<?php 
                      include("connectdb.php");
                     $id = $_POST["idgroup"];
                           if ($_POST['delgroup']!=null) {
                           $delgroup = mysql_query("DELETE FROM groups WHERE id='$id'");
                           echo "Группа была успешна удалена. ";
                     } else {
                     echo "Ошибка. Группа не удалена!";
                     }
                     ?>
```

Comment: Эмъ... а при чем здесь AJAX и POST?

Отправляйте запрос ajax`ом (без формы, по нажатию на кпонку) - и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Если вы это пишете для пользователей, а не для себя, то не храните в открытом виде в input type="hidden" id группы. id можно легко подменить и удалить другую группу.

Comment: @mountpoint, глупо позволять пользователям удалять какую-то группу, так что, скорее, речь идет о какой-то админке.
Но даже если речь о простом пользователе и группе (как, например, группа музыки в ВК), то все равно в коде удаления должна стоять проверка на возможность удаления данной группы конкретным пользователем.
Так что пусть подставляет, что хочет, натворить бед ему все равно не получится. Это лучше, чем мутить всякие хэши и т.д., т.к. в любом случае даже хэш можно подделать и удалить что-нибудь не то. А значит, не стоит усложнять задачу, достаточно ограничить проверкой прав на удаление.

Comment: @BOPOH, да, вы правы. Но все же автору нужно будет использовать хоть какую то защиту, а не тот код, что есть сейчас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form');

        $.post(" путь к php файлу, обработчику формы", form.serialize(), function(){
                // келлбек
             });
        return false;

    });
```

Келлбеком делаете вывод результата.

Comment: Извините, а что такое келлбек и как его оформить?

Comment: @cnofss, имелось в виду "callback" [’kɔ:lbæk]. В данном случае - это  функция обратного вызова. Это еще ничего, встречал тех, кто читает "калбак". ))

Comment: @Deonis, не понимаю вообще, как его сделать. Можете хотя бы пример оставить? Да и можно сделать, чтоб id надо было указывать? Просто у меня этих форм много, а, я так понимаю, это ко всем формам ставиться.

Comment: @cnofss, в общем-то, @ka5itoshka вам уже практически всё показал. Вместо того, где у него написано загадочное "келлбек", вы пишите сценарий, который должен будет выполнится после завершения AJAX-запроса. Эта функция, кроме всего прочего, принимает и ответ сервера.

По поводу id - не понял.

Comment: Можно хотя бы пример скриптом, то что надо писать в келлбеке, просто я вообще не понимаю. На счет id, то есть чтобы форму надо было засунуть в <div id="form1"></div>.

Comment: @cnofss, пример-то я [показать могу][1]. Только вот, поможет ли он вам без базовых знаний, не знаю.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qtduh4oc/1/

Comment: Да помог, спасибо.